# Forward lan traffic to VPN IPsec

Tags: routes, vpn, iptables, lan

I am using from Linux a docker container to set up an IPsec ike connection, specifically it is a stono/ike container.

> docker run -d --privileged --net=host -v sites:/sites stono/ike:latest site user password

This container raises a tap0 interface in the host and creates routes for each subnet of the VPN. The VPN offers me an IP as a client within a range 192.168.50.0/24 and from it allows me to access This is the routing table:

```
192.168.50.0/24 via 192.168.50.14 dev tap0 proto static
192.168.51.0/24 via 192.168.50.14 dev tap0 proto static
192.168.52.0/24 via 192.168.50.14 dev tap0 proto static
....
```

**How can I share these networks on my lan?**

- IPV4 Forward is enabled
- I have created iptables rules to accept the traffic:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A FORWARD -o tap0 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tap0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Finally I have created the static routes on another computer in my lan but I can only ping the ip 192.168.50.14, the ip assigned to me by the VPN server in the tap0 interface, the rest of the host in that network, or in the others, I have no access.

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.50.0/24 via 192.168.1.202
sudo ip route add 192.168.51.0/24 via 192.168.1.202
...
```

Answer (score -1):

What happens if you make the NAT rule more explicit? (I'm assuming 192.168.1.0/24 is your LAN range)

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.50.14
```

Comment: This has not worked for me, I have tried to change --to-source also for the ip of my interface in the lan, 192.168.1.128 and neither.
I have seen a ping -i tap0 to a vpn host not responding, only responding if I use the eth0 interface.
On other occasions I have used nat when the secondary interface gave me access to a subnet, in this case it seems that the ip of the tap0 interface is directly a gateway. I can't get it to work